# C++ application and hardware communication

Tags: c++, oop, hardware, communication

The problem is mostly OOP design problem.
I have a class which handles the connection and communication with hardware (Let's say via USB) - `CommClass`. It has few methods - `connect()`, `disconnect()`, `read()`, `write()`.
The application itself has few other classes that want to communicate with the same HW trough CommClass.
The question - how you usually do that?
I have few ideas in mind:

1. In the parent class or in main create instance of `CommClass`, call `connect()` and pas a pointer to all the classes (constructors). At the end - `disconnect()`.
2. Each method from each class will create an `CommClass` object in the stack when it needs it. - here the problem is that it has to call `connect()` method in order to request a handle to the USB and so on every time...
3. Use static methods from `CommClass`...

Comment: You answered your own question. There's nothing different with having some CommClass shared by several modules than having a plain variable shared between them. The best method is likely to pass it as a pointer to all modules using it.

Comment: As you mentioned Lundin you have answer. If you are not satisfied with your answer then share your problem statement here and also at same time revisit problem. Find out what is missing. Class diagaram or design is always based on problem statement. If problem statement is not clear then noone can give good design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to have a single connection to the device (let's say a USB device) then it makes sense to have one single instance of your `CommClass` or `ICommClass` if you want to have a more elegant design and work with an Interface that is implemented by your `CommClass`. You can also wrap the connection (class or interface) into a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), that way you can make sure that the connection is made and disposed only once. This works best if you expect to use a single connection at a time in a single threaded application. In a multi threaded or multi connection environment you could try using a [object pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the links. That's what I was looking for - some design patterns. Now I have to pick the right one for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution very much depends on the requirements of your application and the nature of your comms connection.  In the simplest case, what you describe in (1) will be probably be adequate.

Personally, I nearly always put comms into a separate thread.  It's a bit more complicated, but it can give significant speed benefits and ensures that your UI doesn't go unresponsive when something strange happens in the comms (like the USB cable being pulled)

The design I've used most often (RS232 comms) uses a slight variation on what you describe in (1).  I have a CComms class as a member of my main application object, which creates a thread to run the comms in.  I then have a very simple message system similar to the one Windows uses which handles all the thread synchronisation passing data between the comms thread and the main application.  The main application then has a few simple functions to send comms messages from other classes and to send the responses back to the relevant class.

I hope that helps a little...

Comment: I started this way. The thread is a bit complicated solution, but I like it. I might give it one more try. How do you deal with a situation when the hardware respond is delayed and the user keeps requesting (clicking on the read() button from example). That will generate a lot of events...

Comment: I deal with that by checking the message queue before I add the new message to it.  If there's already a message of the same ID/type in a queue then I discard it.  The delayed hardware response is exactly the scenario when using a separate thread for comms is a good idea - without it the user won't be able to click the button multiple times because the UI will be locked up.  I agree that it's a more complicated solution, but I've found it to be worth the effort in the long run.